# What is the maximum safe SPI baud rate for this DAC?

Tags: spi, datasheet, dac

I'm trying to communicate with [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8554.pdf) DAC as quick as possible with a microcontroller board, and need to figure out what baud rate would be its maximum limit. There's 50MHz mentioned but I'm not sure.

With what max SPI baud rate can I control this DAC?

And how can I infer from the datasheet that how quick the DAC will settle after an SPI data received?

Answer (score 1):

> With what max SPI baud rate can I control this DAC?

This is given in the datasheet and it is mentioned in the question. But it seems the concern is related to how fast the analog signal changes.

> how quick the DAC will settle after an SPI data received?

The datasheet informs the settling time for two power supply voltages and two different deltas, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: It takes around 10us to settle from 0V to 5V? How can we estimate the settling time for around 10mV increase?

Comment: @GNZ Check the datasheet again. You'll find a paragraph "SETTLING TIME AND OUTPUT GLITCH PERFORMANCE".

Comment: @Seir Thanks for the point. It says: "The DAC8554 settles to ±0.003% of its full-scale range within 10µs, driving a 200pF 2kΩ load." and "Small signal settling time is under 1µs, enabling data update rates exceeding 1MSPS for small code changes." What I understand settling time estimate is 10µ is from zero to full scale and 1µs for small increments.

Comment: @GNZ Correct. Also, _"For good settling performance, the outputs should not approach the top and bottom rails"_. Thus, when using the range near top/bottom, I'd assume a settling time of 10µs.